# Should I approve suggested edits that only add/remove tags?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Are edits involving *only* adding/removing tags to the body or title of the questions acceptable (assuming everything else looks good), or should they be considered too minor?

Comment: "Too minor" isn't a thing any longer but see also now https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Yes, as long as this is the *only* thing that needs to be fixed.**

It's fine to make minor edits. In fact, it's even encouraged in the how to edit page! But they should fix *everything* in the post. If the editor leaves something simple out, edit that in for them. If they fixed only one thing, and there's still a lot to fix, that's too minor. Too minor doesn't necessarily mean very little was changed, it means that there's so much more to fix in the post that the edit barely scratched the surface.

Comment: A simple typo should not be edited by somoeone how goes to the review system. That only wastes the time of the reviewers. Leave such edits to 2k+ users.

Comment: The only exception to this rule is when a tag was added to specifically trigger the right code formatter and coloring for a code listing. A single tag in that exceptional case can make a world of difference and shouldn't be considered minor if it improves the readability of large chunks of code.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it depends on the case.

Personally I have seen lots of suggested edits that did suggest to *add an irrelevant tag* or to *remove an important tag*, IMHO of course. I do usually reject those.

If however I see suggested edits that do really **add value to the question**, I approve them.

Comment: ... and 10 seconds after you click reject, the swarm of robos will approve the retag anyway.

Comment: @DanNeely: ... or more likely, you'll get what's commonly known as "the red bar of death".

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ?

Comment: @DanNeely: that's the message you get that says "This edit was already approved - please visit the post and correc the edit" when you try and reject a post.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy But is that a reason to approve garbage edits? Don't you become a robot if you approve because you might get a red message?

Comment: @Theolodis: I never said that, where are you getting that from? I'm saying that if you try and reject the post, you'll get that message often, which is damm annoying. Depending on the situation, I'll either edit the post again or skip the review (because there's nothing else you can do).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ok, seems to be a misunderstanding ;) I agree

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy oh, looks orange on my screen.