# Retag edit rejected due to being too minor, but new editor ignored retag

Tags: discussion, edits

I spend a lot of time in the [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) tag (often also tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)) and I notice a lot of posts end up there that really should just be tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) since they are working on a wpf app but the question only pertains to the c# part of their code. I try to remove the wpf tag when I notice this.

Up until now this edit has been accepted so I assumed it was a proper thing to do. Recently I edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219777/c-sharp-s22-imap-hide-hardcoded-password) by removing the wpf tag, since it truly has nothing to do with wpf. This was rejected since the reviewer thought it missed the critical edits the post needed. I know there is [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251261/ok-to-approve-edits-that-only-add-remove-tags) about retag edits so I understand why it happened. While I did not think the post needed any editing as it was very clear and concise to me, I agree the edits that were made over mine are good.

My issue is that after the edit the wpf tag is still there. Would it be acceptable for me to re-edit it now and remove the wpf tag or should I just ignore it completely and move on? I am aware this particular question may get removed automatically due to no answers/low votes, but my question is more concerned with the general case of this occuring and what the best approach for me is.

Comment: `Up until now this edit has been accepted so I assumed it was a proper thing to do.`  That's a false assumption to make.  The a large portion of suggested edit reviewers are going to approve pretty much everything, so the fact that an edit is approved doesn't mean that that edit is appropriate, or helpful.

Comment: @Servy so would you suggest I just ignore improper tagging on a question if that is the only edit I notice?

Comment: I'd suggest that any time you find a problem with a question that entices you to edit it, that you read through the whole post and fix all of the problems that you are able to, rather than editing a tag and not looking further.  I'd also urge you to consider the importance of the tag edit.  A question missing a key language tag is going to radically harm the ability of the correct users to find the question, while a merely-tangentially related smaller tag without a lot of followers isn't going to significant impact the viewership of the question either way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try to do that in the future

Comment: @Servy so, you are saying that a bunch of users should see a question they can do nothing about because, yeah? How about if it hurts the questioner because the c# guys that don't like wpf but are able to perfectly fine answer a c# question will never see this question?

Comment: @Braiam They still *would* see the question, as it's tagged C#...

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as an edit that is "too minor", it just doesn't make sense to me. Every helpful edit should be approved, regardless of size of the edit, regardless of _how_ helpful (Given that it is at least slightly helpful, like putting a tag that is related but somewhat low followers) as it _doesn't actively harm the question or the site_ - however, you should also fix any other problems in the post you can find at the same time in a single edit, the better your edit is, the better the question becomes.

Comment: @Servy Consider this; I come accross a question that requires almost no edits, the content of the post itself is 100% on the money - but it's missing a related tag that has low population. I edit the question to add this tag - do you deny or approve this edit? It _is_ a helpful edit, it will expand the reach of the question (Even if just by 10-20 views), and it does not harm the question/site.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton No, that edit *isn't* a helpful edit.  Adding some tangentially related tag with basically no followers is not helping that question *at all*, while at the same time it's consuming a whole lot of people's time reviewing the edit, or who notice the activity on the question only to see that nothing useful was changed about it (if it is in fact approved), the question is also locked from being edited for the entire duration that your edit is being reviewed, preventing *useful* edits.  Such an edit has *made the site a worse place* than if you had not suggested it.

Comment: @Servy I said "_the content of the post itself is 100% on the money_" for a reason, if there is nothing else to change in the post, how is this a harmful edit? Your only downsides are wasting a reviewers time (Which, to review this edit would be just a few seconds), and having the question locked from other "helpful edits", but my question is specifically if there are no other "helpful edits" that can be done with the question. I agree with you that it could be harmful if there is more to change, and someone editing a question should fix all the issues they can find, but that's not my question

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I have *told* you how it's a harmful edit.  You've wasted *several* different people's time for *nothing* in exchange, as you haven't improve the question *in the slightest*.  Then there's the fact that if there are a lot of items in the queue you could be preventing other useful edits on other question from being made.  All of this is of course intentionally omitting the wasting of *your own* time, which could have been spent *actually* improving some post.

Comment: @Servy I guess the part we disagree on is "_haven't improve the question in the slightest_", because in my mind, increasing the reach of the question can bring in answers from different perspectives, allow more people to see the question, and possibly even allow a unique answer that works better than other answers for the same question because it allows the use of another technology (Depending on the related tag).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton If the question is fundamentally asking about that core concept, and is a question that experts of that new tag would be most qualified to answer, then sure, that tag should be on the question, and the *other* tags are fairly suspect.  But just finding random tags with no followers that are only tangentially related is not appropriate at all.  The goal is not to get as many views on a question as possible, if *that* was the goal you'd just tag the 5 tags with the most followers.

Comment: And now you're talking about adding a tag for *some separate technology* that the question isn't even asking about. That's an edit that's actively harmful in it's own right.  Showing a question to people looking for questions about *an entirely separate technology* just because you want more views is a *terrible* idea, and is just going to piss them off before they're forced to remove the tag.

Comment: @Servy "_you'd just tag the 5 tags with the most followers_" - Not really, because you want _relevant_ views on the question, not just any views. But it seems we mostly agree then.