# My edit was rejected, should I suggest the exact same edit again?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I check [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim) (a **PHP** framework) tag regularly. Sometimes I see these questions are actually about the Slim template engine for **Ruby** and should be tagged with [slim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim-lang) instead, so I usually suggest an edit (specially if the question has *low view count in a reasonable time*, which suggests experts in this area are probably missing the question and also no high reputation user has decided to correct these tags).

If my edits are being rejected for not making the post *easier to find* (the main reason why I suggested these edits), but the post has other tags like `ruby` or `ruby-on-rails` or some other tags that makes Ruby guys find it, then it's fine, but what if there are not enough clues in the post content or tags to help the question be found by experts? Like a recent post that only had [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim) tags.

Should I suggest exact same edit that was rejected before? It just seems weird to do so. Also leaving the post as is does not seem to be the right thing to do.

Comment: You can always leave a comment beneath the question suggesting this tag change. That way the OP or a 2k+ user can possibly edit it in if they agree.

Comment: If the edit was rejected, resubmitting it has a high chance of being rejected again.

Comment: Many times, this kind of edit gets rejected when you are _"fixing"_ the tags in an otherwise closable question. The proper tags wont help the question at all, and the edit doesn't do much for the question and could even be counter-productive.

Comment: @Codeer That's what I did and the OP applied my suggestion.

Comment: @yivi the problem is (in this example at least) I'm not familiar enough with ruby to tell if the question needs to be closed. The only thing that comes to my mind is to edit tags so some other people (hopefully watching those tags) can make the call.

Comment: If you are unsure, maybe it is better if you leave it for someone else to make the call, IMO. Just leave the comment as Codeer mentioned.

Comment: I know leaving a comment is an option, in fact it is what I usually do regardless of suggesting an edit or not so at least the OP is informed, but if my suggested edit is worth approving, should `suggesting an edit in comments` be the way to go? Anyway, there seem to be no other options than leaving a comment.

Comment: @Codeer Using comments to suggest tag changes generally has an incredibly low success rate from my experience (I can count on one hand how many time that's actually got a high rep user to apply the changes). (Speaking of which, any high rep volunteers? I can make you a list on gist or something if you have time to review it)

Comment: @Nima I think there's a rule somewhere that suggested edits should never suggest tag only revisions, I find it a bit frustrating but it is what it is.

Comment: Related: [Should I approve suggested edits that only add/remove tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251261/should-i-approve-suggested-edits-that-only-add-remove-tags)

Comment: @AndrewMyers Yeah, I looked hard for the post again, might have been another one of those "twilight zone" moments where I was so sure I saw a post on that but it seems to have vanished from the internet. I couldn't find a FAQ post [(e.g., this one)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) that mentions suggested edits, even though I distinctly remember one saying more or less verbatim "never do it, leave it for high rep users". Maybe it got edited out or I just misinterpreted a burninate rule as being "don't ever do tag edits".

Comment: @jrh I couldn't find a _rule_ anywhere but read some discussions about this. Some say these edits are minor and not helpful and fill up review queues and some say they improve the posts and are worth reviewing. I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Thanks. I didn't see that one when searching for similar questions.

Comment: @Nima Welcome to the lovely world of suggested edits. There's really not much consistency on the rules and some robo-reviewers on both sides, you never know who you'll get for reviewers. Users and SE have occasionally tried to make it more consistent through campaigns / refinement of reject reasons but naturally since this is a community driven site not everyone agrees on what is or isn't a good edit. Do your best to help out within the system's current limitations and hope for the best, sometimes it will be a waste of time, unfortunately. I wish the situation was better. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Also one of the posts that Nima might be talking about might be [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314488/4975230), "I read before that SO very strongly discourages sub 2k Users going on a tag-only edit spree to farm rep, but what is a reviewer supposed to do in this case?", "one moderator did send me a message asking for me to not do 'tag only' reviews". Though as usual we can count on Braiam to write a post defending minor edits (thanks) which has decent acceptance (+54/-9).

Comment: Yes it is one of those. And I was referring to its comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of those situations where unfortunately it's best just to leave it alone. I haven't seen the edit, but I'll assume it was high quality and improved the post as best it could and had a good edit reason.

You suggested an edit and it was rejected, which is frustrating when you're trying to help. I don't think submitting the same edit again is a good idea, we'll just put our trust that the people who reviewed it did the right thing.

What you can do is look over your edit and the rejection reasons. Was there something else you could've improved? Sometimes edits will be rejected if they fail to address all issues with the post, so if there was some spelling or grammar of formatting that could be fixed you could try to address those as well; however, if there was only one tiny problem it probably wasn't relevant. I for one would definitely reject an edit that added a tag but left 3+ formatting problems.

If you truly believe your edit improved the post, you should leave a comment on the post (you can even link the edit) and mention why you think it improves the post. Leaving comments that suggest improvements to the post are what comments are for, so by all means do this.

Once you have 2k reputation, you'll no longer need to suggest edits and instead your edits will be applied automatically. Until then though, thank you for trying to make the site better with your suggested edits!

Comment: In this specific case, it doesn't look as if the rejection was correct. There are no other formatting errors or typos. It might be off-topic but I'm not familiar enough with ruby to judge that. So what op did was the perfect thing. Retag it so people who know ruby can judge whether the question is off-topic. [Link to review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20527726)